# static image does not show in Rails 5 application

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I deployed a Rails 5 app (http://hedera1.ugent.be)

For some reason, one static image does not show on this page:

http://hedera1.ugent.be/projects

the static images are in the folder: /public/images

I show them in the page using the image_tag helper:

```
<%= image_tag "health.jpg" %>
<%= image_tag "elders.jpg" %>
```

for some reason <%= image_tag "elders.jpg" %> does not show in the page.

I don't understand why one image is showing but the other image isn't.

Any help is welcome,

Anthony

Comment: is the image available in asset's directory. if so, have you precompiled the assets?

Comment: hi prakash, thanks, I moved the image to the /assets/images folder, and now the static image shows up on the page

Comment: @Toontje you can mark the above comment as your solution to close the issue :)

Comment: @EmilKampp how can I mark the comment as the solution to my problem?

Comment: @Toontje, aparently you can't. I thought you could. My bad.